# Delete all subdirectory except a subtree

Tags: build.gradle

I'm new. 
I'm trying to create a gradle task that delete all directory except a subset of those.

this is my situation 
 src/main/java
                    test/package1
                    test/package2
                    com/package3
                    com/package4
                    it/package5

and here my code:

```
task deleteFolders(type: Delete){

    group = 'build'
    if(currentTask == "deleteFolders"){ 

        def ftree=fileTree(dir: "$javaDir").exclude('test/package2')
        ftree.exclude('test/package1')
        ftree.visit { FileVisitDetails details ->
            delete  details.file
    }
}
```

but this code delete everything, also the packages inside "exclude".

trying with this other code

```
task deleteFolders{//(type: Delete)

    group = 'build'
    if(currentTask == "deleteFolders"){ 
        delete fileTree(dir: "$javaDir").matching {
             exclude 'test/package1/**' 
             exclude 'test/package2/**'
        }
    }
```

everything work but the com folder is still there empty (i want to remove it).

so, can someone help me to reach this result ?

src/main/java
                    test/package1
                    test/package2

thanks a lot Leo

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try the way as follows:

```
deleteTask = { dealFilePath, destFileName ->
    file(dealFilePath).list().each {
        f ->
            if (!f.contains(destFileName)) {
                delete "${dealFilePath}/${f}"
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please add a description of how your code works. Code-only answers may help the original asker, but are unlikely to help other people who have similar questions later.